# Simplest flowchart using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I would like to have a very simple flowchart using TikZ.

I would very much appreciate if you provide a simple code for this.

For a color, a black and white is fine.

For example, the following is a simple one. But I would like to have blocks of the same width regardless of the text.

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rectangle,thick,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2em] \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto] 
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model}; 
    \node [block, below of=init] (expert) {expert}; 
    \path [line] (init) -- (expert); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: A Sample Flowchart]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add an MWE. Moreover, just search around: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/

Comment: For example, a following is a simplest one. But I would ike to have a block to have the same width regardless of the text. \tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rectangle,thick,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]   
 \node [block] (init) {initialize model};
 \node [block, below of=init] (expert) {expert};
  \path [line] (init) -- (expert);
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: For the future, don't put your example as a comment but edit your question (I've already done it for you).

Comment: And please post complete code we can compile ;). (With a `\documentclass{}` etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle`, see here: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/101651).

Use `below=... of` instead of `below of=`, this way you can also set the distance between the nodes.

To have all the blocks with the same size use `text width=10em` or whatever width you prefer.

If you want to shift the line between the two blocks, you could use `xshift=...`.

If you want a big arrow, change `line width=...`, and, if you want to shorten it, use `shorten >=...` for the tip and `shorten <=...` for the tail.

As cfr told you, don't use `arrows` but `arrows.meta`, you can also change the aspect of the arrow tip with `[length=...,   width=...]`. I've choosen `Triangle` because is similar to the image you posted, but you could choose also `Stealth` or `Latex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{%
    block/.style = {draw=cyan,rectangle,thick,
        minimum height=2em, text width=10em, align=center},
    line/.style = {draw=cyan, line width=4pt, 
        -{Triangle[length=10pt, width=10pt]}, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto] 
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model}; 
    \node [block, below=30pt of init] (expert) {expert}; 
    \path [line] (init) -- (expert); 
    \node [block, below=30pt of expert] (third) {third}; 
    \path [line] ([xshift=-1em]expert.south) -- ([xshift=-1em]third.north); 
    \node [block, below=30pt of third] (fourth) {fourth}; 
    \path [line] ([xshift=1em]third.south) -- ([xshift=1em]fourth.north); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As last questions, how can I get arrow for the line connecting two blocks? Is it possible to change the location of the line between two blocks? (that is, not at the center of a block but like 2cm from the left end of the block.)

Comment: @user12586 If you intended a big arrow, see my renewed answer.

Comment: @user12586 `arrows` is deprecated. Use `arrows.meta` and e.g. `Stealth` instead.

Comment: @cfr You're right, I used arrow because there was `-latex'` in the OP's code snippet. I'll correct my answer asap.

Comment: @cfr Corrected! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Can't upvote again ....