# Tree structure with text boxes at the edges

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

Could you show me how to draw a simple chart like the one given in the image attached. I need to enter text in the bullet format.

Thank you
Chana[image: chart with bullet text]

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/ and https://de.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/29/tikz-series-pt3.html

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope to have understood your instructions correctly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=4.5cm,grow=east,sibling distance=3cm,
                every node/.style={draw,text width=2.5cm}]
  \node {Root}
    child {
      node {\begin{itemize}
       \item duck
       \item koala bear
       \item marmot
      \end{itemize}}
    }
    child{
      node {\begin{itemize}
       \item duck
       \item koala bear
       \item marmot
      \end{itemize}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]